# Exposing a reactive stream through a React Native native module

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to expose something like a Reactive stream of data in a React Native native module? Something like a Publish/Subscribe type of solution would be great. I am really knew to the ReactNative world.

According to the docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#argument-types) I don't see anything like it and I was wondering maybe someone knew the best way to keep a 'connection' open between React Native and my SDK built on Kotlin.

Comment: Look into the event emitter pattern - you pass a callback to the native code, and the native code executes the callback on new events.